# What ads provider for App Store Kids Category app?

Tags: flutter, admob, app-store, app-store-connect

I am using Flutter to develop mobile apps.
In my game I use AdMob as an ads provider. The game is mark as a Kids game (in Kids Category).
For Google Play I had to use Sensitive Categories and Ad Content Rating to meet requirements and the store accept it.
For App Store Connect is not enough. The guideline says that your Kids App cannot use any third-party ads provider unless you will send them the 'documented practices'. Shortly it requires from the ads provider to approve every ad by a human and to serve the ads that are adjusted to kids.
It's reasonable and that is what I set in AdMob ads provider (the same I had to do for Google).
I sent them the link to this documented practices:

1. https://support.google.com/admob/
2. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9283445
   and I ensured them that every ad is checked by human, I also sent them the settings from AdMob where you can see that ads are adjusted to kids.

However, they response was:

> We still noticed that your publicly documented practices and policies for third-party contextual advertising in your Kids Category app are insufficient.

That sad that no additional explanation was given, so I requested the phone call from the Review Team. They called me but it seems that the representative just read what was written in the messages under App Rejected section.
In general she says that they reject all third-party ads providers and when I mentioned Google she started to laugh and said that this ad provider is not good for children.

In my eyes she wasn't professional, because App Guideline clearly says that you can use third-party ads provider if you can provide them their fully documented practices.

So I have a question to you:

1. Did you know any way how to release ios app that includes AdMob ads in App Store Connect in Kids Category? If so, could you give me some advice how to explain it to Apple Review Team?
2. Do you know any other ads-provider that Apple Review Team can accept in Kids Category app?

I tried to explain App Store Connect Review Team that my app will show only the ads that are adjusted to children (link to public practices, ensure that ads are checked by human, sensitive categories, Ad content Rating)